# Smooth CSS animation with four images

Tags: css, css-animations

I have three images that I'd like animate, I want them to infinitely loop from `1->2->3->2`, with each transition being an `ease-in-out`. I have done this, but when the animation restarts the loop, i.e. from `2->1`, it is sudden, rather that easing in as I'd like it to.

I suspect that the animation is not starting by fading in, how can this be fixed?

```css
#cf {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes cfFadeInOutFirst {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes cfFadeInOutThird {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
#cf img.cf-first {
  animation-name: cfFadeInOutFirst;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
#cf img.cf-third {
  animation-name: cfFadeInOutThird;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/250/ff0000/000000" />
  <img class="cf-third" src="https://placehold.it/250/00FF00/000000" />
  <img class="cf-first" src="https://placehold.it/250/0000FF/000000" />
</div>
```

To reduce the CSS code: I was using the `animation-delay` property to stagger the third frame, but then the first and third frames were not easing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `cfFadeInFirst` starts at opacity 1 ... it needs to start at 0:

```css
#cf {
  position: relative;
}
#cf img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes cfFadeInOutFirst {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}  
  10%  {opacity: 1;}  
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes cfFadeInOutThird {
  0%   {opacity: 0;}
  55%  {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
img.cf-first {
  animation: 10s ease-in-out 0s cfFadeInOutFirst infinite;
}
img.cf-third {
  animation: 10s ease-in-out 0s cfFadeInOutThird infinite;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100/ff0000/000000" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/100/00FF00/000000" class="cf-third" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/100/0000FF/000000" class="cf-first" />

<div id="cf">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100/ff0000/000000" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100/00FF00/000000" class="cf-third" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100/0000FF/000000" class="cf-first" />
</div>
```

Comment: Silly me, I copy pasted code. In my mind it was like that, hence I couldn't see the error. Thanks :)